# How to check if multiple columns are empty in a table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a progress bar that checks if the user has filled the data in the database.

so far i have done this, but is there a shorter way to do this? Furthermore i am getting a warning message on MYSQL workbench saying

> "Select is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting: '(',with

```
SELECT * FROM userCertificate 
WHERE certificatename IS NOT NULL 
AND organization IS NOT NULL 
AND location IS NOT NULL 
AND startdate IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I don't know what language you are using at the back. As you are trying to create a progress bar based on the column value than it would be easier if you first map the query result to a `Object` then create your progress bar based on the values of the properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use COALESCE function for multiple columns

```
SELECT *
FROM userCertificate
 WHERE 
coalesce(certificatename, organization, location, startdate) 
IS NOT NULL;
```